# Unable to drag parent div but able to drag child div

Tags: jquery, html, touch, drag

Am using below jQuery plug in

[Touch-box](https://github.com/danniehansen/Touch-box)

My HTML

```
<div class="circleDiv touch-box" data-drag="true" id="circleDiv" >
    <div class="border-circle" id="innerCircle">
        <div class="mini-circles5 touch-box" data-drag="true" id="large-circle">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. <br/><br/> Amirzai Sangin<br/>Minister of Communications<br/> Afghanisthan</p>

        </div>
        <div class="mini-circles1" id="mini-circles1">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s. <br/><br/> John Campbell<br>President and CEO<br> Toranto Waterfront Revitalization Corportation</p>
        </div>
        <div class="mini-circles2" id="mini-circles2">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.<br/><br/> David Woolson<br/>President & CEO<br/> Walla Walla Chamber of Commerce</p>
        </div>
        <div class="mini-circles3" id="mini-circles3">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.<br/><br/> Lee Rainie<br/>Director<br/> Pew Research Center's Internet & American Life</p>
        </div>
        <div class="mini-circles4" id="mini-circles4">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.<br/><br/> Suvi Linden<br/>Member<br/> UN Commission for Digital Development</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS related

```
.circleDiv{
    margin:-35px 70px 0px 0px; 
    width:450px; 
    height:450px;
}
```

But when I try to drag the `circleDIv` am unable to drag the whole div.
When I remove the class `touch-box` from `circleDiv` and place it on `mini-circles5` am able to drag that `mini-circles5` div.

If I put `touch-box` class on both neither the divs are able to drag.

**It is working fine in Firefox, problem is in Chrome**

I need to drag whole parent div `circleDiv`, I dont know what is stopping it.
Any Ideas??